# observableArray unclear behavior when replacing

Tags: knockout.js

In my ViewModel I have:

```
self.collaps = ko.observableArray([0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);

self.shouldShow = function(index) { return self.collaps()[index]; };
```

My test div:

```
<div data-bind="visible: shouldShow(5)">Shown!</div>
```

I `data-bind` a button with `click: show` :

```
self.show = function() {
    // 1. Index 5 gets true after 2 clicks!!? But UI never updates!
    self.collaps()[5] = true;

    // 2. This is push-ing in true starting at index 0
    self.collaps.replace(self.collaps()[5], true);

    // 3. If I combine the two, I get the behavior I want, I think :)
    self.collaps()[5] = true;
    self.collaps.replace(self.collaps()[5], true);

};
```

What is happening here? What is the right way of doing this?

----> [JSFIDDLE for your pleasure!](http://jsfiddle.net/LRQuD/12/) <----

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quote from the `ko` documentation:

> **Key point: An observableArray tracks which objects are in the array,
>   not the state of those objects**
>
> Simply putting an object into an observableArray doesn’t make all of
>   that object’s properties themselves observable. Of course, you can
>   make those properties observable if you wish, but that’s an
>   independent choice. An observableArray just tracks which objects it
>   holds, and notifies listeners when objects are added or removed.

So when you are changing array item's value `knockout` is not notified. You can use `valueHasMutated` function to notify subscribers manually:

```
self.show1 = function() {
    self.test(self.test()+1);

    self.collaps()[5] = true;
    self.collaps.valueHasMutated();
};
```

Comment: Thank you! Does valueHasMutated() exist in the ko docs? I can't find it.

Comment: I haven't seen it there. Maybe I saw it here: http://www.knockmeout.net/. There are a lot of knockout tips.